# Speeding up SQLite Queries

Tags: sqlite

I'm dealing with a large (~10gb) SQLite database containing 3 tables: Documents, which contains an id and a "title" `TEXT` column, Terms, which contains an id and a "term" `TEXT` column, and finally DocumentTerms, which contains an id, a "documentId" `INT`, and a "termId" `INT`, mapping rows from the Terms table to rows in the Document table. If a document contains the same term multiple times, there are multiple entries for that in the DocumentTerms table.

Anyways, my problem is that I need to run a tfidf term weight on each term, which involves these steps (I included the query I think I'll need to get each step):

1. Finding how many times the term appears across all documents -- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DocumentTerms WHERE termId=id`
2. Finding how many documents there are in total -- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Documents`
3. Finding how many documents a term appears in -- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DocumentTerms WHERE termId=id GROUP BY documentId`

Obviously I only need to run #2 once.

With such a big database, each query takes a very long time. Just finding out how many documents there are (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Documents`) takes ~45 seconds.

In an attempt to speed things up, I tried a few pragmas. I only need to run this once, so I don't really care if the DB will be corrupted if I lose power or something during the operation:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
PRAGMA page_size = 4096
PRAGMA cache_size = 16384
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY
PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE
```

How can I speed up these access times??

Comment: I think you should show the exact database structure in your question. You can do that for example using Firefox's SQLite Manager addon and its Database|Export Database Structure command.

Comment: You say it takes ~45 seconds but you should at least tell under which processor and hardware, under a 7Mhz Pentium that's a hell of a speed!

Answer (score 2):

For read-only accesses, most of these `PRAGMA`s do not have any effect.
Only `cache_size` is important; `page_size` might help a little, but must be set before the DB is created.

When a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` takes that long, it is obvious that you do not have any useful indexes.
It is hard to tell without the database structure, but the following indexes are likely to help:

```
CREATE INDEX Documents_Id ON Documents(Id)
```

(Instead of `Id`, you could use any *small* field of the `Documents` table, but it is generally a good idea to have the primary key indexed.)

```
CREATE INDEX DocumentTerms_termId_documentId ON DocumentTerms(termId, documentId)
```

You can check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) how the queries are [executed](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: When you create a column with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, SQLite uses this column as the key for (index to) the table structure. This is a hidden index (as it isn't displayed in SQLite_Master table) on this column. Adding another index on the column is not needed and will never be used. In addition it will slow INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE operations down.
Source: https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuning